# Writing Firebase Database without using their auto generated key in Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using Firebase in my android project where every user will have his details stored like name, phone number, video_url, thumbnail_url etc. Now the way I have used it before in my previous projects is as shown in the pic-

[image: Previous projects]

I did not use the Firebase's auto generated id/Hash but used email id instead. It was easier for me that way. But someone told me that it is unsafe to use emails instead of autogenerated hash/ids and the recommended way is to use hashes. So the question is, is it really unsafe to not use hashes and use email id instead for convenience?

Also if it is unsafe, what is the recommended way to write different key-value pairs under the same hash if we are not inserting all key-values at the same time as an object?

[image: Question Details]

Comment: Firebase push IDs are not meant as a security mechanism, as they don't contain enough entropy to be unguessable. Storing data under email addresses is not uncommon. Either approach can be secure, and non-secure, depending on many factors or your app's needs. If someone told you that your data structure is unsafe, I'd recommend asking **them** what's unsafe about it.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that solves the issue then. So what is the advantage of using Firebase autogenerated ids?

Comment: See firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html and https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe I can simply use emails @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Please don't user emails as keys - it's best practice to disassociate keys (which should be static) from the variable child data they contain. Keys cannot be changed so for example, if a user updates their email address, you would have to delete their main node and re-write it, and then also delete every other reference to that node in your Firebase. Keeping it as a child means only one node would need to be updated; that's one advantage of using autogenerated keys.

Comment: Jay have a point, but that is why there is Functions. I don't see it as a better practice, but as a way to move the problems to another edge, either way, you are gonna have problems eventually, how are you gonna deal with them is the way you choose @Aman I would also recommend to use the UID

Comment: Yes, I agree but I do not have the functionality of deleting the email address in my app. But thanks for the pointer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase's push IDs are more typically used in situations where you'd use a sequential number in more traditional databases. Firebase push IDs are not meant as a security mechanism, as they don't contain enough entropy to be unguessable. For more about them, see this [blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) and [this one](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Storing data under email addresses is also quite common.

Either approach can be secure, and non-secure, depending on many factors or your app's needs. If someone told you that your data structure is unsafe, I'd recommend asking **them** what's unsafe about it.