# How to Read Data From Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to read data from my Firebase database for all questions. For e.g. for question1 I want to store ques,ans and answeredBy into three variables. What I am currently doing is here.

```
private FirebaseDatabase database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
private DatabaseReference 
quizRef=database.getReference("Quiz").child("Questions");
quizRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                ModelClass modelClass=new ModelClass();
                modelClass.setQues(ds.child("question1").getValue(ModelClass.class).getQues());
                modelClass.setAns(ds.child("question1").getValue(ModelClass.class).getAns());

                textViewQuestionText.setText(modelClass.getQues());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            textViewQuestionText.setText("Error occurred");

        }
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried and Tested. You dont have to check for keys like question1,question2 etc

```
       FirebaseDatabase    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Quiz/Questions");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    ModelClass modelClass = (ds.getValue(ModelClass.class));
                    modelClass.getAns();
                    modelClass.getQes();
                    // fetch any key value pair
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

I recommend to use firebase generated hash keys instead of your own keys like question1,question2 etc

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45898277/writing-firebase-database-without-using-their-auto-generated-key-in-android)

Comment: .getReference("Quiz/Questions") and .getReference().child("Quiz").child("Questions")  is same for functionality. Can you explain when we use keepsync(true) what is the best method when we consider brandwith, downloading cost and effective, and efficiency?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the data from your Firebase Database directly using the following code:

```java
DatabaseReference q1Ref = quizRef.child("question1");
q1Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String question = dataSnapshot.child("ques").getValue(String.class);
            String answer = dataSnapshot.child("ans").getValue(String.class);
            int ansBy = dataSnapshot.child("answeredBy").getValue(Integer.class);

            // now you can do what you want with the values stored in the variables
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            textViewQuestionText.setText("Error occurred");

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To read or write data from the database, you need an instance of DatabaseReference:

```
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
// ...
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

To read data at a path and listen for changes, use the addValueEventListener() or addListenerForSingleValueEvent() method to add a ValueEventListener to a DatabaseReference.

You can use the onDataChange() method to read a static snapshot of the contents at a given path, as they existed at the time of the event.

For more information you can [refer to firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)